# Find all elements that are not disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, findall

I got html as follows:

```
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" ......></input></td>
        <td><select>
                 <option val="1">1</option>
                 <option val="2">2</option>
                 <option val="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" disabled="disabled" ......></input></td>
        <td><select disabled="disabled">
                 <option val="1">1</option>
                 <option val="2">2</option>
                 <option val="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
     </tr>
```

I would like to find all td's that has textboxes and dropdowns which are not disabled. I'm tryin to do this:

```
     var res = $.extend({}, $("#myTable").find("td> input:not(:disabled)"), $("#myTable").find("td> 
                                 select:not(:disabled)"));
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `find('selector1, selector2')`.  A comma in selectors, just like in normal CSS, denotes a logical OR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has a `:input` pseudo-selector, which encompasses all the different types of user input elements. You can use that instead of having to write separate selectors for `input` and `select`.

And you can use `:enabled` instead of `:not(:disabled)`.

```
var res = $("mytable td > :input:enabled");
```